# Adding multiple cropped PDF Images into the same PDF page pythonically

Tags: python, pypdf

Is there a way to add, using python, multiple cropped images from a PDF page, read using `pypdf.PdfReader` into the same page created using `pypdf.PdfWriter`?

I'm using Windows 10 and Python 3.7.

Comment: open image as bytestream with `overlay=open("image.png", "rb")` and use `mergePage(overlay)` function of pyPDF2

Comment: Where do I get the ".png" file? I'm using PdfFileReader.getPage() and then .cropBox to crop the image from the pages in existing PDF file. Then I'm trying PdfFileWriter.write method to put the image in a new PDF file. It is to this new PDF File where I need to put more images on the same page.

Comment: these are the details you could have included in your question in the first place, you can always with `mergePage()` insert a cropped section of page you got from `getPage()`. Create blank page with `createBlankPage()`, then merge your desired full page  with that blank page and apply overlay to it.